# Benefits of reallocating memory with std::move instead of copy when vector grows?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am reading the `StrVec` (a vector of strings) example in the C++ Primer 5th edition by Lippman and in the section where reallocation is discussed they mention that it would be much more efficient to `move` all the vectors objects (`strings`) instead of copying. He writes "Our `StrVec`'s performance will be *much* better". I understand this reasoning, but what I am curious about is how this actually affects the objects in the memory.

This newly allocated continuous area is probably (guaranteed?) somewhere else in the memory, so the old area where the vectors objects lie and the new are disjunct, no?

So we still need to *move* the objects over to this new area in the memory, does this not constitute a copy in the memory? I also understand that it leaves the pointers to this old area valid but the values therein are trash. I am guessing that this might be benefit? If so, how? Is it because future memory allocation can use that area? But how will this make the vector implementation faster?

I'll try to illustrate my question to

If the vector looks like this in memory:

```
A:[|strings|]
```

---

And we allocate new space for it

```
B:[----------------]
```

Don't we need to copy over the strings so that:

```
A:[xxxxxxxxx]
B:[|strings|-------]
```

What am I missing here? 
I admit that move semantics is not obvious to me, so I assume I have missed the obvious benefit in this.

**Update**

Must have been tired, missed this sentence in the same section of the book:

> For `string`, we can imagine that each `string` has a pointer to an
>   array of `char`. Presumably the `string` move constructor copies the
>   pointer rather than allocating space for and copying the characters
>   themselves.

Comment: If the vector looked like that, any attempt to change a string in the middle of the vector would require possibly many other strings in the vector. That would break the vector API totally.

Comment: @parham Have you actually tried it? It is possible that there won't be any visible difference in performance. Whether you copy or move, might very well not make any difference as your library might implement a copy-on-write optimization for strings. If you are using gcc, you would need to use std::vector<char> instead of std::string to see a difference.

Comment: @ComeRaczy No C++11-conforming `std::string` implementation can be copy-on-write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character data is not stored in the actual `std::string` object itself, but is stored elsewhere in memory that the `std::string` points at.  So your `std::vector` really looks more like this instead:

```
       [data1a] [data2a] [data3a]
          ^        ^        ^
          |        |        |
VecA:[|string1a|string2a|string3a|...]
```

When using copy semantics, the character data has to be copied to new memory as well, eg:

```
       [xxxxxx] [xxxxxx] [xxxxxx]
          x        x        x
          x        x        x
VecB:[|string1b|string2b|string3b|string4b|...]
          |        |        |        |
          \/       \/       \/       \/
       [data1b] [data2b] [data3b] [data4b]
```

When using move semantics instead, the new `std::string` objects can re-use the original pointers and not have to copy the existing data:

```
       [data1a] [data2a] [data3a]
          ^        ^        ^
          |        |        |
VecB:[|string1b|string2b|string3b|string4b|...]
                                     |
                                     \/
                                  [data4b]
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, I did not consider how a string might actually store its data. I blame the hour but I had failed to grasp the sentence which said "For `string`, we can imagine that each `string` has a pointer to an array of `char`. Presumably the `string` move constructor copies the pointer rather than allocating space for and copying the characters themselves."

Answer (score 2):

The actual character data is not in the `std::vector` itself, but somewhere else in the heap. A `std::string` only contains some housekeeping variables and a pointer to the character data. Thus, by moving those variables, the new `std::string` instances in the reallocated `std::vector` can steal the data pointers from the original `std::string` instances without having to make new copies of the character data.

Answer (score 1):

Because the strings themselves contain pointers to data in yet more buffers!

```
A:[|||\] 
   ||\ [String3]
   |\ [String2]
   | [String1]
   [String0]

B:[....]  //uninitialized
```

If you copy all of the strings in A, they will in turn make copies of those other four buffers.  However, if you *move* the strings to `B`, then they'll just shift the ownership of the existing buffers.